# Function get called twice by event

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have an application containing a form with five input fields. When the user clicks on an input field a tooltip should be displayed, which works fine. The problem comes when I try to remove the tooltip, which happens if the user clicks on another input field. Below is a piece of code from my application, and I hope it's enough to understand how it works.

The arguments that are passed to "showTooltip()" are a DOM reference to the clicked input field, the text that is displayed in the tooltip, and a number (0-4) that is used to find the containing div that's surrounding the clicked input field (all input fields are inside their own div).

The application works fine, but after I've clicked around a couple of times on the fields the following message is displayed in the console: "Node was not found - inputDiv.removeChild(tooltip). I've found out that the reason for this is that the function "hideTooltip()" is sometimes called twice, but I can't find out the reason why this happens.

Any clues?

```
showTooltip: function(inputField, tooltipText, divNr){
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var inputDiv = container.getElementsByTagName('div');   
    var inputDiv = inputDiv[divNr];

    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.className = "tooltip";

    var text = document.createTextNode(tooltipText);
    tooltip.appendChild(text);

    inputDiv.appendChild(tooltip);

    inputField.addEventListener('blur', function() { hideTooltip(inputField, inputDiv, tooltip, inputNode);});
},

hideTooltip: function(inputField, inputDiv, tooltip, nr){
    inputDiv.removeChild(tooltip);

    validateField(inputField);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unbind` is jquery function, so it will not work unless you are using jquery. You will need to use the `removeEventListener` function without jquery. If you do decide to use jquery, I would recommend the `one` (http://api.jquery.com/one/) function that executes an event only once per element. I am not sure if you will need to check to see if the event exists before you call `removeEventListener`.

```
var blurEvent = function() { hideTooltip(inputField, inputDiv, tooltip, inputNode); };
inputField.removeEventListener('blur', blurEvent);
inputField.addEventListener('blur', blurEvent);
```

Comment: Note that using jquery when dealing with events has a huge advantage since it will handle things behind the scenes to make sure the events work with all browsers. IE8 and below do not support the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` functions. Instead you will have to use `attachEvent` and `detachEvent`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried out the code (that really would work as I see it), but by some reason the same error is shown? :/

Comment: I've tried both Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox I get the following error "Node was not found. formDiv.removeChild(tooltip);", in Chrome: "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8".

Comment: There could be some way the blur event is still getting triggered more than once since the remove call is only done right before it is bound again. You should probably move the call to `removeEventListener` to `hideTooltip` function. This way you can be sure that `hideTooltip` will never be called twice from the same event.

Comment: I've tried that too, and the same goes for that. This is really strange :/

Comment: I think I know what is going on. Since you are defining the function inside of the `showTooltip` function, a new reference is being created each time. Thus, the `removeEventListener` is not properly removing the event. You need to declare the function variable such that the reference will remain constant. Once you do that, it seems that you may not even need call `removeEventListener` since "If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded." [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener]

Answer (score 1):

Every time an input field is clicked you're binding the 'blur' event to that field. Click again another event is bound to that field. This is why it's getting called more than once because you're binding everytime. You can unbind first, then add again. There might be a better solution, but this will work:

```
inputField.unbind('blur');
inputField.addEventListener('blur', function() { hideTooltip(inputField, inputDiv, tooltip, inputNode);});
```

**Note:** This will remove ALL event functions bound to 'blur' on that element

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when trying out the code I get the following error in the console "Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'unbind'" ?

Answer (score 0):

In your ShowTooltip function, you are adding an Event Listener that triggers hideTooltip on blur. If you show the tooltip more than once, you are setting more than one onBlur event listener, which means that next time you blur, you will trigger the hideTooltip function twice.

One solution is to unbind the event listener from the inputField when hideTooltip is run.

Good luck.